# How to analyse $y''=\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}+1,x\in(0,+\infty)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

The equation is $f''(x)=\frac{f^{2}(x)}{x^{2}}+1,x\in(0,+\infty)$. Asume $f(x)\in C^{2}(0,+\infty)$.I want to prove that if $\lim_{x\to 0+}xf'(x)=0$ then $\lim_{x\to 0+}f(x)=0$.I think I need to construct some function but I cannot find any of them work.Any help will be thanked.

Comment: If you truly know that $f \in C^2[0,\infty)$, then that is all you need to show that $f(0) = 0$. $f$ is defined at $0$, and any non-zero value of $f$ would require $f''(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to 0+$. Since $f''$ is continuous and defined at $0$, this cannot be. Therefore $f(0) = 0$. However, given the way you are taking limits at $0$ instead of values, I'm guessing that you do not truly want $f \in C^2[0,\infty)$.

Comment: You write one time that $f''$ is defined in $(0, \infty)$ and the other that $f\in{C^2[0, \infty)}$ ...what is the correct one?

Comment: @dmtri sorry,it should be $(0,\infty)$

Comment: @Paul Sinclair, Tree23, so according to Paul Sinclair comment,  you do not need the information that $\lim_{x\to 0}xf'=0$ .

Comment: @dmtri - with the restriction that $f$ is only $C^2$ on $(0,\infty)$, then you do need $\lim_{x\to 0} xf' = 0$. My comment pointed out that $f$ being $C^2$ at $0$ gives the result without the extra limit condition. But I made it a comment, not an answer, exactly because I figured it was an error and the $C^2$ condition should only hold on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair,  Oops you are right!,  I did not pay attention at the last comment of the OP.